# build opencl kernel failure

Tags: build, kernel, opencl

When I use `clBuildProgram` in my OpenCl code it fails with the error code -11 without any log information.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
  ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2048];
    cl_build_status bldstatus;
    printf("\nError %d: Failed to build program executable [ %s ]\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS, sizeof(bldstatus), (void *)&bldstatus, &len);
        printf("Build Status %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
    printf("INFO: %s\n", get_error_string(bldstatus));
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        printf("Build Options %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
    printf("INFO: %s\n", buffer);   
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);    
    printf("Build Log %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    (void)infoinfo(platform_id,device_id);
    exit(1);
    }
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
Error -11: Failed to build program executable [ CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE ]
Build Status 0: CL_SUCCESS
INFO: CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
Build Options 0: CL_SUCCESS
INFO: 
Build Log -30: CL_INVALID_VALUE


CL_PLATFORM_NAME : NVIDIA CUDA
CL_PLATFORM_VERSION : OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.2.1
Device name : Tesla K20m
Driver version : 319.32
Global Memory (MB) : 4799
Global Memory Cache (KB) : 208
Local Memory (KB) : 48
Max clock (MHz) : 705
Max Work Group Size : 1024
Number of parallel compute cores : 13
Is the device available : yes
```

So, just by chance can you guys see any mistake or something weird in the lines above ?

Thank you,

Éric.

Comment: Someone is lying to you. Is the device available as your infoinfo funktion is telling you or is it not available as `get_error_string(bldstatus)` says? Some more code?

Comment: I think it's either my way to call `clGetProgramBuildInfo` or the error code definition I use in the `get_error_string` subroutine. Actually, the `get_error_string` subroutine returns the strings that correspond to an OpenCl error code. That code may not correspond to the cl_build_status code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you might be using clGetProgramBuildInfo() wrong.  The first time it is called, it should should be telling the size of the buffer it needs on the host:

`clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, NULL, NULL, &len);`

then on the host allocate the memory:

`char *log = new char[len] //or whatever you use`

then recall clGetProgramBuildInfo():

`clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, log, null);`

Comment: I updated my code using Austin advice. It works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Eric, almost all of the OpenCL functions that Query the device are this way: Request size of info from the device, allocate the memory on the host, copy info from device to host.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the code and increased the buffer size :

```
  ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[204800];
    cl_build_status bldstatus;
    printf("\nError %d: Failed to build program executable [ %s ]\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS, sizeof(bldstatus), (void *)&bldstatus, &len);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
          {
        printf("Build Status error %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
        exit(1);
      }     
    if (bldstatus == CL_BUILD_SUCCESS) printf("Build Status: CL_BUILD_SUCCESS\n");
    if (bldstatus == CL_BUILD_NONE) printf("Build Status: CL_BUILD_NONE\n"); 
    if (bldstatus == CL_BUILD_ERROR) printf("Build Status: CL_BUILD_ERROR\n");
    if (bldstatus == CL_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS) printf("Build Status: CL_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS\n");  
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
          {
        printf("Build Options error %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
        exit(1);
      }        
    printf("Build Options: %s\n", buffer);  
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);    
        if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
          {
        printf("Build Log error %d: %s\n",ret,get_error_string(ret));
        exit(1);
      }     
    printf("Build Log:\n%s\n", buffer);
    exit(1);
    }
```

I now get this:

```
Error -11: Failed to build program executable [ CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE ]
Build Status: CL_BUILD_ERROR
Build Options:
Build Log:
:4:85: error: must specify ....
```

So, it works.

Thank you for your help.